# Connect slack with simple web api token but not with Slack bot or slack app

Tags: node.js, slack, slack-api

As a leisure project, I created a [small project](https://github.com/kamlekar/gcal-slack) that updates slack status whenever an event is added/updated in Google Calendar (*Just like the Google calendar app on Slack*). Whatever I implemented till now works as expected but I did so by creating a new Slack app, which I don't want to do - In other words, I am trying to integrate Google Calendar with Slack, without any Slack bot or Slack app setup. At least this is what [Zapier](https://zapier.com/) does - It asks for authentication to Google calendar & Slack, and integrates them without having a Slack bot or Slack app.

I referred to [Slack API docs](https://api.slack.com/tutorials/tracks/getting-a-token) but couldn’t find any page helpful enough to work without a Slack bot or Slack app, and simply with a Web API token.

I think I found a [page](https://api.slack.com/methods/openid.connect.token) closer to what I need but this too requires a client ID and client secret which are possible if a new app is created.

Answer (score 0):

It's no longer possible to generate an API token on its own for Slack. If it helps, you can just think of a Slack app as a simple container representing what you want to accomplish. Install the Slack app to get the token and then use the token for that purpose. You don't need to learn or implement OAuth or provide much more than a name to retrieve a token scoped to the activities you wish to accomplish.

Comment: Thanks. I wonder how zapier works without an app or bot?

Comment: There are two Zapier integration types on Slack -- one is what's called a "custom integration" that predates the Slack app platform and is built right into the Slack service by Slack itself -- that's the one that works without an app or bot. There's another version that's built as a somewhat traditional Slack app too: https://my.slack.com/apps/A024R9PQM-zapier